# HTML to XHTML conversion without HTML tag

Tags: html, tags, xhtml, struts, w3c-validation

**Problem:**

My project is using Struts Framework, specifically the html:button tag explained here on [Struts Apache Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/tld-summary.html)

The issue is the `html:button` tag turns into

```
<input>
```

, failing w3c compliance tests. The tag needs to turn into

```
<input/>
```

**Reason:**

I use an html tag specifying xhtml, which is in a template file used in all my other files. All the other files **are not converted** to xhtml though since the tag is in the template file. Is there a way to make all the other files xhtml, without using an html tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add

```
<html:xhtml/>
```

after all the taglib tags on each jsp page

Example of taglib tag:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/taglib/htmlstrut" prefix="html"%>
```